# How do you use one subspec as the dependency of another subspec with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a podspec for [vapor/core](https://github.com/twof/core). It already has a Swift Package Manager manifest file so I'm basing the podspec of of that.

**Package.swift**:

```swift
    // swift-tools-version:4.0
    import PackageDescription
    
    let package = Package(
        name: "Core",
        products: [
            .library(name: "Async", targets: ["Async"]),
            .library(name: "Bits", targets: ["Bits"]),
            .library(name: "Core", targets: ["Core"]),
            .library(name: "COperatingSystem", targets: ["COperatingSystem"]),
            .library(name: "Debugging", targets: ["Debugging"]),
        ],
        dependencies: [
            /// Event-driven network application framework for high performance protocol servers & clients, non-blocking.
            .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git", from: "1.8.0"),
        ],
        targets: [
            .target(name: "Async", dependencies: ["NIO"]),
            .testTarget(name: "AsyncTests", dependencies: ["Async"]),
            .target(name: "Bits", dependencies: ["Debugging", "NIO"]),
            .testTarget(name: "BitsTests", dependencies: ["Bits", "NIO"]),
            .target(name: "Core", dependencies: ["Async", "Bits", "COperatingSystem", "Debugging", "NIOFoundationCompat"]),
            .testTarget(name: "CoreTests", dependencies: ["Core"]),
            .target(name: "COperatingSystem"),
            .target(name: "Debugging"),
            .testTarget(name: "DebuggingTests", dependencies: ["Debugging"]),
        ]
    )
```

I think what I want to do is create a `subspec` for each non-test target, although I'm not sure that's correct, so please correct me if that's wrong. This is what I've got for **Core.podspec:**

```rb
    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    
      s.name         = "Core"
      s.version      = "3.4.4"
      s.summary      = " Utility package containing tools for byte manipulation, Codable, OS APIs, and debugging."
    
      s.description  = <<-DESC
        Utility package containing tools for byte manipulation, Codable, OS APIs, and debugging.
      DESC
    
      s.homepage     = "https://github.com/vapor/core"
      s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.txt" }
    
      s.author             = { "Tanner Nelson" => "" }
    
      s.ios.deployment_target = "10.0"
    
      s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/twof/core.git", :branch => "master" }
    
      s.source_files = "Sources/**/*.swift"
      s.exclude_files = [
        'Pods/**'
      ]
      s.module_name = "Core"
    
      s.swift_version = "4.2"
    
      s.dependency 'SwiftNIO'
    
      s.subspec 'Debugging' do |debug|
          debug.source_files = 'Sources/Debugging/**/*.swift'
      end
    
      s.subspec 'Async' do |async|
          async.dependency 'SwiftNIO'
    
          async.source_files = 'Sources/Async/**/*.swift'
      end
    
      s.subspec 'Bits' do |bits|
          bits.dependency 'SwiftNIO'
          bits.dependency 'Core/Debugging'
    
          bits.source_files = 'Sources/Bits/**/*.swift'
      end
    
      s.subspec 'COperatingSystem' do |os|
          os.source_files = 'Sources/COperatingSystem/**/*.swift'
      end
    
      s.subspec 'Core' do |core|
          core.source_files = "Sources/Core/**/*.swift"
    
          core.dependency 'Core/Debugging'
          core.dependency 'Core/Async'
          core.dependency 'Core/Bits'
          core.dependency 'Core/COperatingSystem'
          core.dependency 'SwiftNIOFoundationCompat'
      end
    end
```

However, the above fails linting with the following errors

```
 -> Core (3.4.4)
    - ERROR | [Core/Bits,Core/Core] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - ERROR | [Core/Bits,Core/Core] xcodebuild:  Core/Sources/Bits/BitsError.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Debugging'
```

It seems like `Core/Debugging` is not being used as a dependency for `Core/Bits` and `Core/Core`, and I can't tell why that is. If it helps, you can find the full output of `pod spec lint Core.podspec --verbose` [here.](https://gist.github.com/twof/6c9c4293a8db3689505edb24d08cf828)

Comment: Have you tried using just `bits.dependency 'Debugging'`?

Comment: 'Debugging' points to this pod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Debugging

unfortunately

Comment: How does your podfile look like? You have to specify your Source first, if you are using private pods. `source 'https://github.com/me/my-podspecs.git'` This way its looking for your pods first and you shouldnt run into naming problems

Comment: Can you explain what podfile you're talking about? I thought I'd just need the podspec in order to publish.

Comment: Nvm, I thougt of something different but you are not trying to integrate the pod into a project yet. But your first attempt was right, its `Core/Debugging` otherwise you get these namespace collisions.

Comment: Did you import the Pod as `Core/Debugging` in `Core/Sources/Bits/BitsError`?